# GORM id assigned to another domain class

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an `User` Class and I want to create a new Class called `UserSettings`.
The `UserSettings` class should be contain the User ID which also should be the ID of itself.

The `UserSettings` looks like this:

```
class UserSettings {
    String listDefaultTimePeriod = "today"
    User user
    static mapping = {

        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'user'
        user column: 'user_id'

    }
}
```

If I start the project I get this Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: User, at table: user_settings, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user_id)]
```

How can  I map `UserSettings` correctly to use the user_id as primary key?

Comment: use `static hasOne = [ user:User ]` instead of `User user`. in this case you don't need `user column: 'user_id'` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I didn't understand you correctly... (and stumbled now over the same question for a one-to-one association ...)

To have "The UserSettings class should be contain the User ID which also should be the ID of itself." I found the following solution (for a one-to-one association):

```
class User {
    String name

    static hasOne = [setting: UserSetting]

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'user_id'
        setting cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }

    static constraints = {
        setting unique: true
    }
}

class UserSetting {

    static belongsTo = [user: User]

    String listDefaultTimePeriod = "today"

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'user_id', generator: 'foreign', params: [property: 'user']
        user insertable: false, updateable: false
    }

}
```

The link to the hibernate documentation for the "foreign" generator:
[hibernate generators](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)

And the link to a blog-post which I found, describing this solution:
[Grails foreign id generator](http://blog.swwomm.com/2011/09/grails-foreign-id-generator.html?showComment=1472559650866#c2536575969847920065)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relation from UserSetting to User, the id of the User is automatically called 'user_id' in the database.

I would design the classes the following way:
(please keep in mind, that not every database allows you to name a table 'user'...)

```
class User {

    String name

    static hasMany = [settings: UserSetting]

}

class UserSetting {

    static belongsTo = [user: User]

    String listDefaultTimePeriod = "today"

    static mapping = {
        table 'user_settings'
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }

}
```

And in the controller save method, you have to fill the user_id to the user_settings_id like:

```
@Transactional
def save(UserSetting userSettingInstance) {
    ...
    userSettingsInstance.id = userSettingsInstance.user.id
    ...
}
```

- I prefere to name the class as a SingleInstance and the database guys prefere to have the table named as the multiple... (thats the reason for the table mapping).